# pattern matching of an expression using wild parameters with sympy

Tags: python, expression, sympy, matching

I want to check if an expression has a specific structure und find the parameters within the structure.

Example:

```
import sympy as sym

v = sym.Symbol('v',integer=True)

p0 = sym.Wild('p0', exclude=[v, 0] ) 
p1 = sym.Wild('p1', exclude=[v, 0] ) 
p2 = sym.Wild('p2', exclude=[v, 0] ) 
p3 = sym.Wild('p3', exclude=[v] ) 
p4 = sym.Wild('p4',properties=[lambda pp: pp==-1 or pp==1])

x=(1 - sym.exp(21*sym.I))/(1*(1 - sym.exp(3*sym.I)*sym.exp(-2*sym.I*sym.pi*v/7)))/2

s=x.match( p0 / ( p1 - p2 * sym.exp( p4 * sym.I * 2 * sym.pi * v / 7 + p3 ) )  ) 
print("Match ",s)
print("Number of args",len(x.args))
```

So there is no match, although the structure is right. Moving the last /2 at a different place

```
x=(1 - sym.exp(21*sym.I))/(2*(1 - sym.exp(3*sym.I)*sym.exp(-2*sym.I*sym.pi*v/7)))
```

will give a match.

I was looking at x.args each time and the very first x had 3 arguments, the latter only 2, but putting an additional /2 at the end of x, leading to 3 arguments again is working.

```
x=(1 - sym.exp(21*sym.I))/(2*(1 - sym.exp(3*sym.I)*sym.exp(-2*sym.I*sym.pi*v/7)))/2
```

Any ideas whats going on here, or how to find out why the matching is sometimes not recognized?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The expressions and the pattern look like

```
In [18]: x
Out[18]: 
            21⋅ⅈ       
       1 - ℯ           
───────────────────────
  ⎛          -2⋅ⅈ⋅π⋅v ⎞
  ⎜          ─────────⎟
  ⎜     3⋅ⅈ      7    ⎟
2⋅⎝1 - ℯ   ⋅ℯ         ⎠

In [19]: x2
Out[19]: 
           21⋅ⅈ      
      1 - ℯ          
─────────────────────
            -2⋅ⅈ⋅π⋅v 
            ─────────
       3⋅ⅈ      7    
2 - 2⋅ℯ   ⋅ℯ         

In [20]: pattern
Out[20]: 
           p₀           
────────────────────────
         2⋅ⅈ⋅π⋅v⋅p₄     
         ────────── + p₃
             7          
p₁ - p₂⋅ℯ               

In [21]: x.match(pattern)

In [22]: x2.match(pattern)
Out[22]: 
⎧         21⋅ⅈ                3⋅ⅈ               ⎫
⎨p₀: 1 - ℯ    , p₁: 2, p₂: 2⋅ℯ   , p₃: 0, p₄: -1⎬
⎩                                               ⎭
```

I would say that `x` should match `pattern` although with the `1/2` absorbed into the numerator `p0` so the matched values would be different.

This looks like a bug in match to me so best to open an issue:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: The issue is https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21868

Comment: I also found that for xx=exp(j*3*v)+exp(-j*3*v)+4 the command xx.find(sym.exp(j*p5) + sym.exp(-j*p5) ) is empty, where ( p5=sym.Wild('p5') ).

Comment: Better to post on the issue rather than here